# How to send an email using adb intent, in android 8.0 os?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, adb

I have a command:

```
adb shell "am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -d my_email@com --es 
android.intent.extra.SUBJECT "my subject" --es android.intent.extra.TEXT "my text" -n "my 
package" -c android.intent.category.EMAIL -t '*/*' --eu android.intent.extra.STREAM 
file:///sdcard/image.jpg"
```

this command is working just wonderful on multiple android devices.
but- I have some devices who refuse to attach the file...
any idea to force them? (the file exists in the same path in all of the devices)

Comment: note: the command is working on android 7.0 and 8.0 OS, but then not working on another device with OS 8.0

Comment: Could you specify the device where this isnt working ?